# Need help figuring out what mysterious bar is on top of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-tablayout

So I have a fragment Tab Layout, Status bar and SupportActionBar on top of screen. On "Start" button click I have them all hiding. on "stop" button click they all become visible again. However, directly underneath the SupportActionBar/ActionBar is some other bar and I don't know what it is. But whatever it is, the Status Bar and this mystery bar are both under colorPrimaryDark in styles.xml

Here's the BEFORE "start" click: 
(I commented out status bar so it wouldn't disappear)

[image]

When I click "Start" and everything hides except my commented out status bar and then you see the mystery bar behind the SupportActionBar/Action Bar and I have no clue what it is:

[image]

It's not the actionBarItemBackground (i tried it).
Can anyone figure out what this mystery bar can be that's directly underneath the SupportActionBar/ActionBar?

Here's my XML:

[image]

Here's the manifest:

[image]

Here's the styles.xml

[image]

Edit:

This is the code for hiding the ActionBar. Behind this action bar is the orange mysterious bar. I have code for hiding Status bar and TabLayout but it has no affect on ActionBar.

```
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){  
        getSupportActionBar().hide();    
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you hiding/showing plus the style XML and Application tag from the manifest?

Comment: @Mehmed, I included my code and XML above.

Comment: Also, included manifest and styles.xml

Comment: Can you share the code called when you click that buttons and full xml for the activity? Also, it would be better if you share as text rather than screenshots.

Comment: I posted the code and the XML is also posted on here under under "Here's my XML"

Comment: Please add your code as text, not images

Comment: I posted the code for SupportActionBar at bottom, what code specifically you looking for?

Comment: In your layout, do you have an AppBarLayout and a Toolbar in it?

Comment: I posted my XML above yesterday, I don't use AppBarLayout because I don't want view to scroll. I don't use toolbar either.